# Simplifying the words "had to" and "won't" in this context

Tags: word-meaning

> My car broke down today and I **had to miss** such an important meeting.
>   My car just **won't** start.

How do you simplify the word *won't* in the sentence above?

How do you simplify the words *miss* and *had to*?

I do not really want to teach grammar of *have to* to my mother. She is an absolute beginner and really eager to learn English. But she is very reluctant to communicative classes. She is around 60 and of course I will teach her grammar in right time but now I need your help.

Answer (score 4):

It's a little unclear exactly where the confusion lies here - is it in the use of contractions? Past-tense verbs? Multiple definitions for "have" and miss"?

"Had" is the past tense of "have."
"Have to [verb]" in this case is an imperative or obligation like "must [verb]" or "forced to [verb]". See [Definition #2 here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have).

> I was forced to miss the meeting due to something out of my control.

To "miss" in this case means "fail to attend," or let something pass by. See [Definition #7 here.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miss?show=0&t=1408464578)

> I missed my doctor's appointment yesterday.

This is a different use than the idea of ["missing" a person because they are gone](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miss?show=0&t=1408464578), but it's similar in that there's something/someone you wish to encounter but do not.

"Won't" is a contraction, or a shortening of a word signified by the use of an [apostrophe in place of the missing letters](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/apostrophe#apostrophes_showing_omission).
It's (it is) short for "will not." This is equivalent to "refusing to."

> My car will not start. My car refuses to start.

If "won't" is unclear, then perhaps discussing contractions in general is a good idea.

Other common ones include:

- "can't" for "cannot" (unable to do something)
- "shouldn't" for "should not" (it's a bad idea to do something)
- "wouldn't" for "would not" (hypothetically refusing to do something)
- "don't" for "do not" (telling someone not to do something)

Answer (score 1):

In this context "had to" means "was forced to".

"Miss" is used in the context of attendance - you were expected to attend an important meeting, but were unable to do so.

We can clarify this further by substituting the phrase above: "was unable to attend" instead of "had to miss". This inverts the emphasis on both halves, but ends up meaning the same thing.

"Won't" is a contraction meaning "will not".

To plug these into the original sentence, it could read something like this:

> My car broke down today, and I was unable to attend such an important meeting. My car just will not start.

Answer (score 0):

> My car broke down today and I **missed** an important meeting. My car just won't start/**doesn't work**.

It really doesn't get easier than that, I'm afraid. Even my changes if anything only make it marginally simpler - "to miss" is just a vocable that needs to be learned.
And do/don't/does/doesn't (or the respective longer forms do not/does not) should also be one of the earlier English lessons.